# tinymce covered by white diagonal rectangle in chrome and safari?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am trying to use Tinymce in my site. For some reason when I use it on chrome and safari it is covered by a big white diagonal rectangle....

It is working fine in firefox.

Here is an example screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see tinymce is behind the diagonal...

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Looks kind of like some dirty april fool's trick by Apple.

Comment: Its the 5th of April though....

Comment: Is this page somewhere that I can visit?